# angular-nvd3 legend text truncated

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

I just started using angular-nvd3 and can't seem to find out how to keep the legend text from being truncated. I'm using the bar+line graph and the legend text uses the "key" property of the data for the legend text, appended with (left axis) and (right axis). If the key property name is longer than 20 characters it's being truncated and appended with an ellipses. How do I keep the legend text from being truncated?

Answer (score 0):

```
legend: {
    align: false,
    padding: 40,
    width: 100
},
```

The align false will stop truncating, the padding and width are extra to help it look nice.